# Long array with didSelectRowAtIndexPath Issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have an array which has lots of data which is dispalyed on the TableView. I am trying to push the selected row name. So every time I have to write IF method, while every row has the same method. Is there a way to just push the selected row?

Thanks from now.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    SecondViewController *DetailViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    if ([[Brands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"A"]){

}

    if ([[Brands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"B"]){

}
.
.
.
```

Comment: it depends ...what are you going to do if xxx isEqual:@"A" ?

Comment: I am just going to push their names to the next view. Is there different method instead of isEqual:@""?

Comment: no there is not any other method for that but a better approach will be setting A as a key to a NSMutableDictionary and the names to this key's value. then you can get better performance results..

Comment: Thanks, iremk. I don't know why I get -1 vote? While I trying to get better result.

Comment: can you explain, why you are checking the if condition ?

Comment: @MidhunMP I just know this method. Thats why I am asking is there a different method?

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi: I mean what are you doing if `if ([[Brands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"A"])` or  `if ([[Brands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"B"])` condition occurs ?

Comment: @MidhunMP I am going to make the selected row will change the label name as in the row name.  `label.text = @""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many times I found my answer. Thanks again for your responds.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

SecondViewController *push = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

NSString *detail=[Brands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

label.text = detail;
```

}